# FFC Cambridge Process and impure reactants

Tags: electrolysis

The [FFC Cambridge process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFC_Cambridge_process) with platinium electrodes allows the reduction of almost any metal oxide to a pure metal, with an oxygen byproduct.

So far, so good.  What I'm trying to understand is how it would handle mixtures of of materials.  For example, if it was a mixture of iron oide and titanium oxide, what would it do?  Which oxide would be reduced preferentially?  (I think in reverse order of reactivity?) If it was contaminated with calcium carbonate, would the chloride ions switch places with the carbonate?

Ultimately this is a question about how electroylsis works with complex solutions - so what would it do?

Comment: Where do you see chlorine ions ?

Comment: [FFC process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97dfa1GoF7w) > next step is that the pellets are placed into a crucible or reduction vessel that's filled with very pure molten salt normally this will be **calcium chloride**.

Comment: Correct, should be chloride, fixed

Comment: [Research Papers
The FFC Cambridge process and its relevance to valorisation of ilmenite and titanium-rich slag
G. Z. Chen
Pages 96-105 | Received 05 Mar 2014, Accepted 08 Aug 2014, Published online: 19 Nov 2014](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1179/1743285514Y.0000000073?journalCode=ympm20)